# GCC 4.6 seems not to working

Tags: gcc, c++11

I've downloaded binaries for GCC 4.6, I've set up toolchain executables in code::blocks and yet this fails to compile (I can compile it from the command line though):

```
int main()
{
int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (int& x : array)
  x *= 2;
    return 0;
}
```

What shall I do in order to properly configure compiler in code::blocks?

Comment: @phooji The err msg I'm getting is that initializer is expected before ':' which would suggest that this compiler doesn't support this feature, but as I've sais I can compile this file with **this** compiler from command line

Comment: @There - Is it a feature in `C++0x` to write `for` loop like that ? Moreover, `x` can take the reference of integer variable but `array` is of type `int[]`. I know it decays to `int*` but still are n't the lvalue and rvalue types are different. Are these are new features though ?

Comment: @There - Online compiler "ideone" also unable to compile the snippet you posted.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Sounds like your IDE is not sending the `-std=c++0x` param to your compiler.

Comment: @phooji yes, it looks like that, any way to fix it?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Does this help? http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en3.html#x3-270001.11.6

Comment: @phooji - you know what, I've started looking at the website you've suggested but in the mean time I've also created new project in code::block and guess what? It freaking works! Awsome! Going to play with C++11, o yeahhh!!!

Comment: You can delete your question, then. (Congrats on getting it working.)

Answer (score 3):

you have to tell g++ that it should compile with **c++0x** syntax:

```
g++ --std=c++0x prog.cpp -o prog.x
```

because *this* is new C++0x *ranged-for* syntax:

```
for (int& x : array)
```

if this doesn't work, confirm that you use GCC 4.6+

```
towi@havaloc:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

because [4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) is *not* enough.